# Output file and directory listing

Tags: python-3.x

I am struggling with figuring out how to get the right output on a directory listing.

```
for filename in os.listdir("C:\\scripts"):
    print(filename)

Outputs:
folder1
folder2
folder3

for top, dirs, files in os.walk('c:\\scripts'):
    for nm in files:
        print(os.path.join(top, nm))

Outputs:
c:\scripts\folder1\Document1.txt
c:\scripts\folder1\Document2.txt
c:\scripts\folder1\Document3.txt
c:\scripts\folder2\Document1.txt
c:\scripts\folder2\Document2.txt
c:\scripts\folder2\Document3.txt
```

But I am trying to figure out how to end up with the following formatting of the output:

```
Directory folder1 contains:
Document1
Document2
Document3

Directory folder2 contains:
Document1
Document2
Document3
```

and so forth, any pointers on how I can achieve this would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `dict` to store the data and then iterate it. use `os.path.basename` to get the dir name

**Ex:**

```
import os

result = {}
for top, dirs, files in os.walk('c:\\scripts'):
    for nm in files:
        result.setdefault(os.path.basename(top), []).append(nm)

for dirname, filenames in result.items():
    print("Directory {} contains:".format(dirname))
    for filename in filenames:
        print(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'walk()' function will give you each file is the subtree with their absolute path.

If you only need to get the files under one level of subdirs, you could start with 'listdir()' as you did, place those dirnames in a list, and finally go through you list to select the files with 'isfile()'.

Example :

```
import os

first_lvl_dirs = [dn for dn in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(dn)]

print (first_lvl_dirs)

for dn in first_lvl_dirs:
  print (f"{dn} contains : ")
  for f in os.listdir(dn):
      print(" - "+f)
```

Answer (score 0):

The complete code for the format that you requested could be something like this

```py
import os

source_dir = 'test'
for item in os.listdir(source_dir):
    folder = os.path.join(source_dir, item)
    if (os.path.isdir(folder)):
        print("Directory {} contains:".format(item))
        for file in os.listdir(folder):
            print(os.path.splitext(file)[0])
        print()
```

If you need to list only one-level deep directories and their file contents.

Comment: This is exactly the formating I looking for, to go down several sub-directories would you go for a os.walk() insted?

Comment: Yes, you should use `os.walk` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Python's [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) iterates on a `root` directory, and each iteration returns all subdirectories and files in that root as a 3-tuple. So, what you could do is:

```py
for top, dirs, files in os.walk('c:\\scripts')[1:]:
    print("Directory {} contains:".format(top)
    for nm in files:
        print(nm)
```

Note the `[1:]` in the loop is to skip the actual top folder argument and *walk* all its subfolders directly